# Numpy repeat converts `nan` to `str`

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This numpy behavior seems a little weird.

```
>>> type(np.array([1, np.nan]).repeat(2)[2])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

But when I make the first param a string

```
>>> type(np.array(["a", np.nan]).repeat(2)[2])
<class 'numpy.str_'>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: that is cause by repeat , it is already str np.array(["a", np.nan])[1]
'nan'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this way of viewing the arrays will make the difference clearer:

In the first case, `np.nan` is a float, so all elements are floats:

```
In [310]: np.array([1, np.nan]).repeat(2)                                            
Out[310]: array([ 1.,  1., nan, nan])
In [311]: _.dtype                                                                    
Out[311]: dtype('float64')
```

In the second, there's a string, which can't be made into a float, so the dtype for the whole array is string - including `np.nan` which is now 'nan':

```
In [312]: np.array(["a", np.nan]).repeat(2)                                          
Out[312]: array(['a', 'a', 'nan', 'nan'], dtype='<U3')
In [313]: _.dtype                                                                    
Out[313]: dtype('<U3')
```

The `repeat` has nothing to do with this.  It's how `np.array` constructs an array from the list, choosing the best common `dtype`.

```
In [321]: np.array(["a", np.nan],dtype=float)                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

Comment: Understood. But how do I get an array with `nan` preserved as `np.nan

Comment: Specify `object` dtype.

Comment: Did this and it worked. Thanks `np.array(v, dtype=object).repeat(lengths)`

Answer (score 3):

from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

> dtype : data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the **minimum type required to hold the objects** in
>   the sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array.
>   For downcasting, use the .astype(t) method.

in your first example`1` and `numpy.nan` can be cast to a `numpy.float64`; in the second a `str` (i.e. `str(numpy.nan)  = 'nan'` ends up in your array).